# Is there a way to create a static public URL for an image in my personal OneDrive using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What I'm trying to achieve via Microsoft Graph API is to upload an image to my personal OneDrive and get a URL which my code will then send to someone else to view at a later date. This URL must require no authentication and must able to be used in an img tag for a website.

I've managed to upload the image and use the /thumbnails endpoint to get the URL but it seems like the URL expires after some time (I think around 24 hrs). I have also tried:

1. using the /content endpoint - that also created a short-lived URL.
2. using the /createLink endpoint then encoding the URL and using the /shares endpoint - that also created a short-lived URL.

So...anybody know of any alternatives to create a non-expiring public URL for images on personal OneDrive accounts using Microsoft Graph API?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hows you're getting the URL using the code - through Graph API ?

Comment: I think this link may be helpful if you use personal account.[link](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/622).